# Add reg file located in a subfolder with spaces in his name

Tags: powershell

Hello i am trying to execute a reg file (with spaces in his name) located in a subfolder named : "Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC".

My actual script is :
`reg import $PSScriptRoot + '\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC.reg'`

I also tried :
`regedit /s $PSScriptRoot + '\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC.reg'`

Doesn't work :(
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses to force PowerShell to evaluate the string concatenation before passing the resulting value to `reg.exe`:

```
reg import ($PSScriptRoot + '\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC.reg')
```

Alternatively, use an expandable (double-quoted) string:

```
reg import "$PSScriptRoot\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC\Remove Extra Folders from Windows 10 This PC.reg"
```